# Modal validate: If the input email is not unique, it should show up the error message

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'd like to validate inside modal.
Now, I can validate if the input is empty.
But how can I validate if the input isn't unique, then show up the error message.
For example, "The Input email address is already used."

Can somebody help me ?

I'm using Laravel10, Bootstrap@5.3.

This is my code: modal.blade.php

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit-profile-{{ $user->id }}">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content border-primary">
            <div class="modal-header border-primary">
                <h3 class="modal-title text-primary">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-pen"></i>&nbsp; Edit Profile
                </h3>
            </div>
            
            <form action="{{ route('update') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
                @csrf
                @method('PATCH')
            
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="John Doe" value="{{ $user->name }}" autofocus required>
                        <label for="name">Name</label>

                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            Please choose a username.
                        </div>                        
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" value="{{ $user->email }}" placeholder="name@example.com" required>
                        <label for="email">Email address</label>
                        
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            Please choose a unique email address.
                        </div>   
                    </div>
                           
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="avatar" class="form-label d-block">Avatar</label>
                        @if ($user->avatar)
                            <img src="{{ $user->avatar }}" alt="{{ $user->name }}" class="rounded mb-3" style="object-fit: cover; width: 200px; height: 200px;">  
                        @endif
                        <input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatar" class="form-control" aria-describedby="avatar-info">
                        <div class="form-text" id="avatar-info">
                            Available file format: jpeg, jpg, png, gif only. <br>
                            Maximum file size is 1048 KB.
                        </div>
       
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            Error!!
                        </div>                        
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer border-0">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>   

<script>
    (() => {
        'use strict';

        // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
        const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation');

        // Loop over them and prevent submission
        Array.from(forms).forEach(form => {
            form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
                if (!form.checkValidity()) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                }

                form.classList.add('was-validated');
            }, false);

            // Add an input event listener to check validity on input change
            form.addEventListener('input', event => {
                if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input') {
                    event.target.classList.remove('is-invalid');
                }
            });
        });
    })();
</script>
```

This is HomeContorller.php

```
public function update(Request $request) {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|min:1|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|min:1|max:255|email|unique:users,email,'. Auth::user()->id,
            'avatar' => 'max:1048|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg,gif',
        ]);

        $user = $this->user->findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);
        
        $user->name  = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        
        if($request->avatar) {
            $user->avatar = 'data:image'. $request->avatar->extension(). ';base64,'. base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->avatar));
        }
        $user->save();

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

I tried to add Javascript code, but it doesn't work.

```
<script>
    (() => {
        'use strict';

        // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
        const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation');

        // Loop over them and prevent submission
        Array.from(forms).forEach(form => {
            form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
                if (!form.checkValidity()) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                }

                form.classList.add('was-validated');
            }, false);

            // Add an input event listener to check validity on input change
            form.addEventListener('input', event => {
                if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input') {
                    event.target.classList.remove('is-invalid');
                }
            });
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already use the `unique` validation rule to check if the email is unique. However, the error message is not being displayed in the modal because you are redirecting back without passing the error messages. You need to pass the error messages to the view. You can do this by flashing the error messages to the session. Then in your modal, you can check for any error messages for the email field and display them.

```php
public function update(Request $request) {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|min:1|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|min:1|max:255|email|unique:users,email,'. Auth::user()->id,
        'avatar' => 'max:1048|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg,gif',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }

    $user = $this->user->findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);
    
    $user->name  = $request->name;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    
    if($request->avatar) {
        $user->avatar = 'data:image'. $request->avatar->extension(). ';base64,'. base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->avatar));
    }
    $user->save();

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

And in your modal, you can display the error message like this:

```html
<div class="form-floating mb-3">
    <input type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" id="email" value="{{ old('email', $user->email) }}" placeholder="name@example.com" required>
    <label for="email">Email address</label>
    
    @error('email')
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            {{ $message }}
        </div>
    @enderror
</div>
```